# Can't get chrome.runtime.onMessage to listen

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When the user clicks my item in the context menu, I want to send a message from `background.js` and listen for it in my content script, `script.js` so that I can run some code to manipulate the DOM.

I copied the example code from the [Chrome Message Parsing docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) as-is, however I can't get the listener function to trigger.

Here's my `manifest.json` file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Background image downloader",
  "description": "Easily lets you download images that are set as background-image in CSS",
  "version": "0.0.1",

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "contextMenus"
  ],

  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "script.js"
  ],

  "icons": {
    "16": "assets/icon_16.png",
    "48": "assets/icon_48.png",
    "128": "assets/icon_128.png"
  },

  "background" : { "scripts": ["background.js"] }
}
```

Here's `background.js`:

```
// Inject the content script into each page (script.js)
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL("script.js");
s.onload = function() {
  this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);

// Handle the click on the context menu
function getClickHandler(info, tab) {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    console.log(tabs[0].id);
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
      console.log(response.farewell);
    });
  });
};

// Create the context menu
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title" : "Download image",
  "type" : "normal",
  "contexts" : ["all"],
  "onclick" : getClickHandler
});
```

And here's `script.js`:

```
console.log('script.js loaded');

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    debugger // This never gets triggered
    console.log(sender.tab ?
                "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                "from the extension");
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
  });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See [extension architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). You're injecting a script element into the background page. And it's not a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). See the [official sample extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples) for the actually working code (filter the list by `executeScript` in particular)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sample code without understanding is usually a bad idea.

By creating a `<script>` tag, you inject code in the current page's context - which happens to be your background page.

1. If you need your code to execute *alongside* normal pages, you need [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

   The docs describe it in ample detail, but there are 2 broad ways to use them: declare them in the manifest and programmatically inject.
2. There are limitations to content scripts, in that they [can't interact with pages' own code](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment). That's where [the snippet you quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script) comes in - but only from within an already running content script.

   In many cases you don't need that; in *any* case, code injected this way loses its special extension privileges and can't use `onMessage`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. The solution was simply declaring the script in the manifest with `content_scripts` and matching to `"http://*/*", "https://*/*"`. The listener is working now. Thanks for your help!